# overriding the binary predicate when doing a lexicographical compare in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

If I have two arrays, a1 and a2 in ruby, to do a lexicographical comparison I do a1 <=> a2.

Is there a way to override how ruby compares each element?

What I'd like to do is something like

```
a1.collect(&:name) <=> a2.collect(&:name)
```

**without the collect** because that's creating two new arrays (e.g. if we're sorting an array of arrays, a ton of time would be spent in the allocator).

I could write my own lexicographical compare function, but that seems very anti-ruby and I'm not sure if it would be faster because the the amount of time spent in ruby space (vs C space).

edit: another example would be for doing a case insensitive lexicographical compare of two arrays of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a custom block to `sort_by` instead:

```
meta_array = [a1, a2]
meta_array.sort_by do |arr|
  arr.collect(&:name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's dangerous to change how arrays are compared, so you should create a subclass of `Array`. Suppose your `a1` and `a2` belong to `A`, which is a subclass of `Array`. Then, redefine `<=>` as follows:

```
class A; def <=> other; collect(&:name) <=> other.collect(&:name) end end
```